# Cordova Plugin CodePush - updates lost after relaunching the iOS App

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-app-center, hockeyapp, code-push

I have a live App on the Apple store and it uses Microsoft AppCenter CodePush to install live updates. Cordova plugin: [cordova-plugin-code-push](https://github.com/microsoft/cordova-plugin-code-push).

When I publish an update for iOS the update is correctly installed but the next time I launch the app the update is gone!

There aren't any logs that indicate that the update has been rolled back and no other error logs.

- My code:

```
export function initCodePush() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const codePush = getPlugin('codePush');
    console.log('{CodePush} - launching..');

    codePush.sync((syncStatus) => {
      // Called when the sync process moves from one stage to another in the overall update process
      // Possible values: 'UP_TO_DATE', 'UPDATE_INSTALLED', 'UPDATE_IGNORED', 'ERROR', 'IN_PROGRESS',
      // 'CHECKING_FOR_UPDATE', 'AWAITING_USER_ACTION', 'DOWNLOADING_PACKAGE', 'INSTALLING_UPDATE'.
      console.log(`{CodePush} - status: ${window.SyncStatus[syncStatus]}`);
    }, {
      updateDialog: false,
      installMode: window.InstallMode.ON_NEXT_RESTART,
      mandatoryInstallMode: window.InstallMode.IMMEDIATE,
    }, (downloadProgress) => {
      // capturing download progress and currently doing nothing.
      console.log(`{CodePush} - download progress: ${JSON.stringify(downloadProgress)}`);
    }, (err) => {
      console.error(err);
      reject(err);
    });

    // Since `codePush.sync()` is a blocking call, this `resolve()`
    // will only be called after one of the callbacks gets called.
    resolve();
  });
}
```

- The logs:

```
19:07:53.591135-0400 {CodePush} - launching..
19:07:53.591303-0400 {CodePush} - status: CHECKING_FOR_UPDATE
19:07:53.781102-0400 [CodePush] Checking for update.
19:07:54.169450-0400 [CodePush] Reported status: {"status":0,"appVersion":"1.2","deploymentKey":"MY_PROD_KEY","previousLabelOrAppVersion":null,"previousDeploymentKey":null}
19:07:55.250285-0400 [CodePush] An update is available. {"appVersion":"1.2","deploymentKey":"MY_PROD_KEY","description":"PROD iOS - latest master with brown","downloadUrl":"https://codepushupdates.azureedge.net/storagev2/some-long-probably-sensitive-key","isMandatory":true,"label":"v16","packageHash":"along4ssh4sh","packageSize":5279914,"failedInstall":false}
19:07:55.250332-0400 {CodePush} - status: DOWNLOADING_PACKAGE
19:07:55.250407-0400 [CodePush] Downloading update
19:07:56.436079-0400 {CodePush} - download progress: {"receivedBytes":17996,"totalBytes":5279914}
19:07:56.446796-0400 {CodePush} - download progress: {"receivedBytes":79970,"totalBytes":5279914}
[...]
19:07:57.090707-0400 {CodePush} - download progress: {"receivedBytes":5160960,"totalBytes":5279914}
19:07:57.090832-0400 {CodePush} - download progress: {"receivedBytes":5279914,"totalBytes":5279914}
19:07:57.661513-0400 [CodePush] Package download success: {"deploymentKey":"MY_PROD_KEY","description":"PROD iOS - latest master with brown background","label":"v16","appVersion":"1.2","isMandatory":true,"packageHash":"long4ssp4ckageh4sh","isFirstRun":false,"failedInstall":false,"localPath":"cdvfile://localhost/library-nosync/codepush/download/update.zip"}
19:07:57.661754-0400 {CodePush} - status: INSTALLING_UPDATE
19:07:57.664468-0400 [CodePush] Installing update
19:08:00.312666-0400 [CodePush] Applying full update
19:08:00.463188-0400 [CodePush] Install succeeded.
19:08:00.463264-0400 {CodePush} - status: UPDATE_INSTALLED

// App restarted because mandatory update. Logs:
19:08:01.986773-0400 {CodePush} - launching..
19:08:01.986928-0400 {CodePush} - status: CHECKING_FOR_UPDATE
19:08:02.059582-0400 [CodePush] Checking for update.
19:08:02.219584-0400 [CodePush] Reported status: {"status":1,"label":"v16","appVersion":"1.2","deploymentKey":"MY_PROD_KEY","previousLabelOrAppVersion":"1.2","previousDeploymentKey":"MY_PROD_KEY"}
19:08:02.233273-0400 [CodePush] App is up to date.
19:08:02.233618-0400 {CodePush} - status: UP_TO_DATE
19:09:12.337888-0400 [CDVTimer][codepush] 3.816962ms

// Next App launch:
19:09:13.829947-0400 {CodePush} - launching..
19:09:13.831466-0400 {CodePush} - status: CHECKING_FOR_UPDATE
19:09:13.914494-0400 [CodePush] Checking for update.
19:09:14.372443-0400 [CodePush] App is up to date.
19:09:14.372535-0400 {CodePush} - status: UP_TO_DATE
```

The status is "UP_TO_DATE" ..but it silently reverted the App to NO UPDATES at all. No rollbacks in the report.

I have reproduced this issue numerous times (~20). I am proficient with CodePush CLI And AppCenter dashboards.

NOTE:

- The only change in the live update is one single line for the background color (as a test)
- AppCenter CodePush dashboard counts the installations as successful. The rollback count is 0!
- Live updates always work on Android. Updates are kept after the App is relaunched.
- This issue seems to be intermittent (but consistent). A couple of hours ago updates were not lost relaunching the app.
- This issue never presents using the iOS Simulator

**Versions:**
- Cordova: v8.1.2
- cordova-ios: v5.0.1
- iOS: 12.3.1
- release build
- Engine: [Ionic engine](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview) v4.0.0 (WKWebview)

Comment: UPDATE: this seems to be a CORS issue. Requests using a custom origin (eg. `ionic://`) intermittently fail. See https://github.com/microsoft/cordova-plugin-code-push/issues/558

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you call `codepush.notifyApplicationReady` when your app starts up. Although Codepush documentation says this isn't required when you do a sync(), I noticed some similar behavior to what you describe when I didn't have that.

This may not be your problem since you stated there were no rollbacks, but I'm leaving this here in case other people find this post with a similar problem.

Comment: I stuck up in the same issue. I was calling codepush.notifyApplicationReady after my platform ready code in ionic, it's not working though

Answer (score -1):

This was not due to a CORS issue (even though for a while we saw some CORS errors in the logs - the AppCenter team may have fixed them in the mean time).

It's still not clear why live updates get lost after hard-closing the app (without any error logs).

Using [this fork](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-code-pushfork) though the live udpates work and stick around on app re-launch.

Using the [latest master of cordova-plugin-code-push](https://github.com/microsoft/cordova-plugin-code-push/commit/6bbab8d37921b75c6b198eecfc453a7c3a95fcfd) instead it does not work. I'm still very confused as to why. In the forked plugin I only added some extra logs and it defaults to latest master of the plugin (but using it directly it does not work..). Verified this multiple times.

Comment: That fork should not exist. It has no value over the existing plugin, and is out-dated.

Comment: What I can tell you for sure is that that fork works and the official plugins doesn't. Happy to delete it though as we have now hosted it internally.